# Enable gzip compression on merged magento files (css,js) with nginx

Tags: magento, nginx, gzip

pagespeed says that 2 resources are not gzipped: .css and .js files merged by magento and located in media directory.
How can i gzip that too? gzip already enabled.

thanks

Comment: you can enable gzip compression on the server.

Comment: it's already enabled, but looks like it does not process files merged by magento

Comment: @SamProvides did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```

in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf` file.

I have not tested this.Please perform this on staging/development server first.

Comment: I already have gzip enabled, just like that, but magento merged files do not get compression.

Comment: @GiacomoRiccitiello , If you have merged the files using the Magento why do you want to again compress using gzip?

Comment: gtmetrix says that Compressing http://www.mywebsite.com/media/js/fb968rr3db3766e0073fef059c5cadf5.js could save 357.9KiB (74% reduction).

Comment: What is the average page load time of your site? I do not think that you need more compression.